# Latest record by Rank

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to pick the latest record which appears twice. I used the Rank to identify the latest by making `Rank = 1`. But I need both the latest SEQ but Rank shows 1 and 2. How do I make both the Ranks 1 for `SEQ = 5` so I could pick both? Below is the code I tried.

`row_number() over (partition by PART,SEQ order by TO_NUMBER(SEQ) desc) as Rank`

```
SEQ            PART        RANK  

5               P1          1

5               P1          2

4               P1          1

4               P1          2
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use:

```
rank() over (partition by part order by to_number(seq) desc) as rank
```

That is, remove `seq` from the `partition by`.

`rank()` gives ties the same value, so multiple rows will have `1`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Gordon! But after I remove SEQ, I see the Rank as 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on. I do not see SEQ = 5 with the same Rank because it's now treating the records as separate rows.

Comment: @Nick . . . Are you using `rank()` or `row_number()`?

Comment: I was actually using row_number(). I changed it to rank() and it's working. Thanks Gordon!